# JomSocial Extension causes error: 0 String could not be parsed as XML

Tags: module, extensions, administrator, joomla-3.3.x, jomsocial

I have installed a JomSocial extension and now I am seeing an error:

> 0 String could not be parsed as XML

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcG3t.jpg)

The same error message is also presented in the title tag of my administrator source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Error: 0 String could not be parsed as XML</title>
    ...
```

[screenshot of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKd28.jpg)

Do I need to uninstall my JomSocial extension?  If so, how do I do this? Or should I upgrade my Joomla version? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: If you can't get into Joomla admin because of this extension then go into the file system and rename the directory of that extension so that Joomla won't find it to run it. If it's an admin component then it will be under administrator/components. If it's an admin module then it will be under administrator/modules. If there's a plugin then it will be somewhere under the plugins/ directory structure. In that case find the relevant php file and rename it. You should be able to identify it from the creation date/time or from the parts of the jomsocial download file.

Comment: i am trying! but it remains!

Comment: Mr.Robbie Jackson thank you very much. i tried many times but my problem disolved .i tried to renames them but the message was remained until now.

Comment: When I commented on your earlier question to say "Please edit your question to include copy-pasted text." I didn't mean please post new duplicated question, I meant please click on the "edit" hyperlink under your question to improve your question.  I'll delete your first question.  Please do not post another duplicate question.

Comment: I have removed your earlier question and edited this question.  If you would like to add new details or correct something about my edit, please do so by editing THIS question.  @morteza Welcome to JSE and please take our [tour] and read [ask] to better understand our posting expectations.

Comment: @mortezamohammadivand.kh What version of Joomla are you using? Are you using the latest version on JomSocial? Have you tried contacting the developer on JomSocial?

Answer (score -1):

Invalid JomSocial license, or license check failed. Validate your license or buy a  valid license, install the latest version, or ask their [support forum](https://www.jomsocial.com/forum).